# React cannot read property of undefined when accessing from e.g. IF statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Redux turned my app state to props and I would like to access the properties of certain props once the API request is done. Yet, my page can't render as I get the above message.

kicking off GET reqest:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.renderRoles(this.props.params.roleID);
};
```

Rendering users does work though:

```
renderUsers(){
  return this.props.roleDetails.userList.map((user)=>{
    return(
    <li className='list-group-item eventUserList' background-color="#f2f2f2" key={user._id}>
      {user.userName}
    </li>
      );
     });
   };

  render() {

    const { handleSubmit, fields: {} } = this.props;
```

***This is the problem part. Somehow, properties of this.props get undefined if I look for their properties:***

```
    if (this.props.roleDetails.roleName){
    return (
```

If I only look for this.props.roleDetails, it does work, but not when for its properties:

```
    if (this.props.roleDetails){
    return (


  <div className='container-fluid'>
  <form>
    <div className="roleDetails">
      <div className="roleName">
      {this.props.roleDetails.roleName}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="roleUsers">
      <div className="userDetails">
      <h4 className="listOfUsers">Role Owner :</h4>
      <ul>
      {this.renderUsers()}
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div className="submitRole" onClick={this.submitForRole.bind(this)}>Apply</div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    );
}else {
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
}
  }
}



function mapStateToProps(state) {
return{
  roleDetails: state.api.roleDetails,
  refreshedRole: state.api.refreshedRole
}
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'roleView',
  fields: []
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(roleView);
```

Other similar questions are related to functions, but in my case is about accessing props therefore .bind(this) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (this.props.roleDetails.roleName)` looks like `roleDetails` `undefined` befor You get data with request, so if You will try to get access to it's property `roleName` you will get an error.

`if (this.props.roleDetails && this.props.roleDetails.roleName)` shouldn't throw errors.

And it's not good idea to fetch data in `componentWillMount`, use `componentDidMount` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You gave me a great idea. I just put an if statement verifying if Roledetails !== undefined  before the one looking for the.roleName property. That does work.